Evaluating the integral of the total energy of the EM field in a nonlinear dielectric
In general, the energy of the electromagnetic field is given by [1]:
$$ H = \int \vec{H}\cdot d\vec{B} + \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{D}. \tag{1} $$
This integral can clearly be split into the magnetic and electric contribution and since the materials of interest I want to consider do not experience magentization, this integral can be easily evaluated with $\vec{H}=\vec{B}/\mu_0$ [1]:
$$ \int \vec{H}\cdot d\vec{B} = \frac{|\vec{B}|^2}{2\mu_0}. \tag{2} $$
However, the electric contribution in (1) is not as easy to evaluate due to the materials nonlinear response. First, we can rearrange the integral using integration by parts [2]:
$$ \int \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{D} = \vec{E}\cdot\vec{D} - \int\vec{D}\cdot d\vec{E} \tag{3} $$
Now we need the connection between $\vec{D}$ and $\vec{E}$. For the $i$th component it reads [1,2]:
$$ D_i = \left(\sum_{n\geq 1} \epsilon^{(n)} : \vec{E}^{\otimes n} \right)_i \tag{4} $$
$$ = \sum_{n\geq 1} \sum_{j_1 \ldots j_n} \epsilon_{i j_1 \ldots j_n}^{(n)} E_{j_1} \ldots E_{j_1} \tag{5} $$
Plugging this into (3) leads to integrals for the form
$$ \int \sum_{ij} x_i dx_j = \sum_{i\neq j} x_i x_j + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i} x_i^2 \tag{6} $$
for the first order and analogously for the higher orders. The integrals have different prefactors depending on the indices.
However, this does not seem to coincide with the results provided in Ref. [2], Eq. (1.55):
$$ \int \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{D} = \sum_{n>0} \frac{n}{n+1} \vec{E}\cdot \epsilon^{(n)} : \vec{E}^{\otimes n} \tag{7} $$
For example, directly evaluating the term $n=1$ of the integral using (6) yields
$$ \frac{1}{2} \sum_i \epsilon^{(1)}_{ii} E_i E_i, \tag{8}$$
which is clearly only the diagonal contribution of (7).
What am I missing?
References:
[1] N. Quesada & J. E. Sipe, Opt. Lett. 42, 3443 (2017)
[2] P. D. Drummond and M. Hillery, The Quantum Theory of Nonlinear Optics (Cambridge University, 2014)

Please don't delete your original question and create a new version of it.  If your question is close as being unclear, you should edit it to make it understandable so it can be reopened, not create a wholly new version of the question.

$\epsilon$ is usually assumed to be symmetric. Then there is an orientation of the cartesian coordinate system in which $\epsilon$ is non-zero only on the diagonal (with eigenvalues on the diagonal). Maybe they consider all components with respect to such coordinate system.

With no loss of generality, $\epsilon_{ij_1...j_n}$ is symmetric in the $j$'s. For the existence of energy, you also need it to be symmetric with all the indices. If not, the work is path dependent, or equivalently, you can have a non zero work along a closed loop.
With this observation, it is relatively straightforward to integrate the function:
$$
\begin{align}
D\cdot dE &= \sum\epsilon_{i_0...i_n}E_{i_1}...E_{i_n}dE_{i_0} \\
&= \sum\frac{\epsilon_{i_0...i_n}}{n+1}(E_{i_1}...E_{i_n}dE_{i_0}+E_{i_0}...E_{i_n}dE_{i_1}+...+E_{i_0}E_{i_1}...dE_{i_n})\\
&= d\left(\sum\frac1{n+1}\epsilon_{i_0...i_n}E_{i_0}...E_{i_n}\right)
\end{align}
$$
You need to be careful with the indices. Part of your confusion may stem from your mistake in (6). The correct expression is rather:
$$
\int \sum x_idx_j = \sum_{i<j}x_ix_j+\frac12\sum_i x_i^2 = \frac12\sum_{i\neq j}x_ix_j+\frac12\sum_i x_i^2 = \frac12\sum_{i,j}x_ix_j
$$
which is consistent with all the expressions. In your original formula, you overcounted the off diagonal terms. For example:
$$
\int xdx+xdy+ydx+ydy = xy+\frac12x^2+\frac12y^2 = \frac12(x^2+xy+yx+y^2)
$$

I am not quite certain that the $x_i dx_j$-integral is correct this way. Writing it out explicitly, I get $3\times 3$ summands. Three of those are the diagonal terms and six others are off-diagonal. Each off-diagonal term appears twice since $x_i x_j$ = $x_j x_i$. "$i<j$" is three terms instead of six, so there would be a factor two missing. Am I right?

No that's my final point, you are overcounting twice the off diagonal terms:$d(xy) = xdy+ydx$. Even if you have $D(D-1)$ differential terms, you only get $D(D-1)/2$ terms after integration. Study closely the spelled out $2\times2$ case, it's exactly the same in higher dimensions.

I don't see it unfortunately. In your last example, if I integrate term by term, why to I not get $\frac{1}{2}x^2+ xy + yx+\frac{1}{2}y^2$ for each term, respectively? These terms are written out there so why would I be overcounting them?

You cannot integrate each term separately. $xdy$ does not derive from a potential (integrating over a closed loop gives the area of the loop, not zero). The same holds for $ydx$. As previously mentioned, you need to integrate them together $xdy+ydx = d(xy)$ (differential of product), so you only have one term, not two.

I suggest you to look at this this related question.
Integrating the first-order term of $\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{D}$
$$
\mathbf{E}\cdot \left(
\frac{d\mathbf{P}^{(1)}}{d\mathbf{E}}
\right)d\mathbf{E} = \epsilon_0 E_i \epsilon^{(1)}_{ij} dE_j
$$
can be done the following way by exploiting the permutation symmetry of the susceptibility tensor:
$$
\epsilon_0 \int E_i \epsilon^{(1)}_{ij} dE_j = 
\frac{1}{2}\left(
\int E_i \epsilon^{(1)}_{ij} dE_j +
\int E_j \epsilon^{(1)}_{ji} dE_i
\right) =
\epsilon_0 \frac{1}{2} \int d[\epsilon^{(1)}_{ij}E_i E_j] =
\epsilon_0 \frac{1}{2} \epsilon^{(1)}_{ij} E_i E_j.
$$
This approach can be generalized to any $n$, giving the desired $n$-th order nonlinear Hamiltonian.
You can also do it using integration by parts as you attempted:
$$
\epsilon_0 \int E_i \epsilon^{(1)}_{ij} dE_j = 
\epsilon_0 E_i \epsilon^{(1)}_{ij} E_j - \epsilon_0 \int E_j \epsilon^{(1)}_{ji} dE_i.
$$
Re-arranging and using the permutation symmetry of $\epsilon^{(1)}_{ij}$ gives
$$
2 \epsilon_0 \int E_i \epsilon^{(1)}_{ij} dE_j = \epsilon_0 E_i \epsilon^{(1)}_{ij} E_j.
$$

Could you please elaborate on the last "=" in the second equation; where does the factor 1/2 come from? Was it missing in the step before?

The factor 1/2 in Eq.2 comes from re-writing the l.h.s. as a sum of two identical terms, and then using the permutation symmetry to change the order of the indices in the second term.
